# Get IG_MEDIA_ID from Instagram post link

Tags: instagram, instagram-graph-api

I have a link to some instagram post/reel (e.g. https://www.instagram.com/reel/C0w1dkGr4fi/). I need it's `ig_media_id` to query the Instagram Graph API, how am I supposed to obtain this, it doesn't show up in the docs as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `/{instagram-business-account-id}/media` endpoint with the relevant fields to get the `ig_media_id`. Use the following:

```
graph.facebook.com/{instagram-business-account-id}/media?fields=id, ig_id, permalink
```

You would need to map your reel url with the permalinks presented in the responses and then pick up the respective `ig_id`.

Pro Tip: You can use the Facebook Graph API explorer to test the endpoints quickly:

[https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/](https://Facebook%20Graph%20API%20explorer)